# Character array reuse

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm writing a Win32 console application in Visual Studio 2010.

Consider one function that take two `char*` as parameters.

Following is prototype of function:

```
void WriteApplicationFile(char *mappname,char* MessageString)
{
   //Do some File related stuffs.
}
```

Now the following calls are working perfectly:

```
WriteApplicationFile("FirstOne", "Append Me");
WriteApplicationFile("FirstOne", "Append Another");
```

But if I try the same thing with some character array thing this will give me assertion, and throw me on assembly.

The following code is not working:

```
char * LocalBuffer  = new char[100]; 
sprintf(LocalBuffer,"Number of jobs in Queue %d",JobsCount);
WriteApplicationFile("SAAZshadowProtect",LocalBuffer);
free(LocalBuffer);
LocalBuffer = NULL;
//Work fine.
//...
LocalBuffer  = new char[100]; 
sprintf(LocalBuffer,"Log file name %s",LogFileCharName);
WriteApplicationFile("SAAZshadowProtect",LocalBuffer);
free(LocalBuffer);   // I got assertion here..
LocalBuffer = NULL;
```

Where am I going wrong?

One more thing is that I want to handle all assertion and bugs with try-catch block. How would I do this?

Comment: use plain old malloc if you're in C. moreover freeing in order to reallocate same size ? just this is giving me the chills... memset is there for a reason.

Comment: It seems like some buffer overrun has occurred before Localbuffer.

Comment: Please check if some memory overwrite has occurred.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(v=vs.80).aspx. If you have access to internals of WriteApplicationFile, you can review it for possible memory overwrites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If use `new[]` you must use `delete[]`, not `free()` or `delete`. Replace:

```
free(LocalBuffer);
```

with:

```
delete[] LocalBuffer;
```

There appears to be no reason to be dynamically allocating memory. The size of the buffer is a compile time constant, is not large (no stack overflow) and the buffer appears to not be required to live beyond the scope in which it was allocated.

As this is c++ strongly suggest using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which will handle dynamic memory management for you and [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) which is typesafe and avoids specification of fixed sized buffers instead of `sprintf()`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::ostringstream out;
out << "Number of jobs in Queue " << JobsCount;
const std::string s(out.str());
```

If access to a c-style string is required use `std::string::c_str()`.

Additionally, the argument types of `WriteApplicationFile()` are `char*`, not `const char*`, so passing a string literal to the function would be causing undefined behaviour *if* the function modifies the arguments.

Comment: No it again give me assertion on line code delete[] LocalBuffer;

Comment: And i cant use std:: as suggested by one my senior person.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade, 1) find out why `std::` is prohibited and why your life is being made more difficult. 2) `new char[]` followed by a `delete[]` will not be the cause of the assertion. Either remove parts of code until the error disappears then reintroduce code to locate the source of the error or post more of your code for people to comment.

Comment: The code given by me is sufficient please try it on win 32 API consol application you will get the same.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade, the `new[]` followed by `free()` is a bug which you have corrected (everywhere?). There _must_ be another error elsewhere, which is not visible in the posted code.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade, I would remove the calls to `WriteApplicationFile()` to being with and see if the error occurs.

Comment: This shouldn't cause a problem, now that you've fixed the free/delete issue.  Since it is, it's likely you're screwing up your memory somewhere else and just not seeing it until here.  Double frees have cost me days in debugging.  Basically, once you screw up your memory management, everything after has to be considered bogus.  And there's not always any way of telling when you messed up your memory.

Comment: @hmjd It could be, and I've used implementations where the reverse would abort.  More likely, however, is a buffer overrun.

Comment: @hmjd Given the name of the function, I suspect that the arguments to `WriteApplicationFile` should be `char const*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I do agree but it is impossible to be sure give the absence of the function body.

Comment: @hmjd Yes.  But I'd say that either the name is wrong, or the arguments should be `char const*`.  The name of the function very definitely says that it won't be modifying them.  (Of course, mis-named functions are fairly common.)

Comment: Guys i locate it but very silly thing,I am using array of LocalBuffer  = new char[100]; 
and asigning 212 character to that array total memory overlap.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade, using `ostringstream` would prevent it.

Comment: dynamic charecter allocation not giving error while assinging it but will give error when i frre it.

Comment: i am died to use std:: interface but i dont known why my seniors not allowing me.

Answer (score 2):

First, are you programming in C or in C++.  The code you present
looks like C, but you speak of a try/catch block, which can only
be C++.

In C++, use `std::ostringstream` and `std::string`.  Any other
solution is simply incorrect.

In C, you should use `snprintf`, instead of `sprintf`.  It is
almost impossible to use `sprintf` safely.  (How many characters
are in `LogFileCharName`, for example.)  And don't use dynamic
allocation when you don't have to.  (That holds for C++ as
well; there should be no `new` or `delete` (nor `malloc` nor
`free`) in the code you show.

As to what is going wrong, there are at least two possible
problems in the code you show: you're allocating memory with
`new[]`, but freeing it with `free` (undefined behavior), and
you're not checking the length of `LogFileCharName` before
calling `sprintf`, so you could be overwriting the end of the
buffer.